# Topology for test functions

Tags: fa.functional-analysis

One naive way to define a topology on test functions ${\mathcal D}(\Omega)$ would be to exhaust $\Omega$ by compacts $(K_n)$ and to take the metric induced by the semi-norm system
$$
{\| f \|} _ {n} := \| f \|_{C^n(K _ {n} )},  $$ 
i.e. 
$$
d(f, g) = \sum _ n  2^{-n}  \frac{ \|f-g\| _ {n} }{ 1+\|f-g\| _ {n} } 
$$
I read (without any reference) that this yields a non-complete space.

Do you know a reference or a concrete example how to show non-completeness?

Comment: Oups, the answer is simple.

Take $f_n$ such that $0 \le f_n \le 1$ with
$f_n = 1$ on $K_n$ but $f_n = 0$ outside $K_{n+1}$. Then 
$\| f_n-f_m \|_k = 0$ for all $k \le \min(n, m)$. Therefore, letting $N$ such that $\sum_N^\infy 2^{-j} < \epsilon$  yields $d(f_n, f_m) < \eps$ for all $n, m > N$.

Comment: Do you wish your question to be closed?